# PostgreSQL pglogical to native logical replications

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I have a setup with `pglogical` extension where I replicate multiple databases to one. I have a requirement to use native logical replication instead of `pglogical`.

The goal is to continue the sync from where it was stopped during the stopping `pglogical` subscription

I tried disabling the pglogical subscription and creating a new logical `slot`, `publication` and `subscription`. though the status would say streaming but the changes are not replicated.

What would be the best solution to do achieve this?

Comment: I'm not certain you can seamlessly flip from pglogical to native replication, but in any case you probably want to reuse the same replication slot instead of creating a new one.